# Combinatorial analysis problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**Case 1**

Have $90 + x\text{ elements,}\quad x < 15$

How many combinations of $60$ elements are possible? (order doesn't count)

**Case 2**

$$50 + x\text{ elements,}\quad x < 15$$

How many combinations of $30$ elements are possible? (order doesn't count)  What is the correct formula for calculating the result?

Sorry if I'm asking something obvious. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since the order does not matter you should use [Combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

1. Case 1. $$\dbinom{90+x}{60}=\frac{(90+x)!}{60!(90+x-60)!}$$
2. Case 2. $$\dbinom{50+x}{30}=\frac{(50+x)!}{30!(50+x-30)!}$$